# Jupyter in vscode - convert to raw NBCovert or deactivate cell?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

I'm used to hitting the R key in jupyter to change it to raw NbConvert type which deactivates it, but I don't see that option in the shortcuts for vscode. Is there a way to change a cell to raw nbconvert in vscode, or some equivalent way of preventing a cell from accidentally being run? raw format is perfect because it's easy to tell

Answer (score 8):

apparently (from what I know) there's no shortcut key to change a cell to raw. However it's possible to change a cell to raw NbConvert from the GUI.

[image]

From the picture above, you can see that this Python/raw is shown at the bottom right of a cell. Just simply click on the Python word and choose raw from the pop out selection and boom. You get a raw NbConvert cell. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: How do you get see "Python" and "raw" to show in the lower right of the cell? I don't have anything there in VS code 1.72.2

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the above answer by @Boom and continuing to answer there is clickable UI at the bottom right corner > then search for  type.